# C# Installer Output fails to start

Tags: c#, wpf, installation, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to generate an installer for my wpf project. After doing some research, I've found the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022 Extension and looked up for tutorials on how to work with it. While watching I tweaked with it and generated primary outputs from the two projects, I coded.

After editing name, description and so on, I built the installer and clicked on 'Install'. It worked and now I have an installer that throws out my projects saved in two dll files and a shortcut for both of them. However, when I tried to run it, windows asked me, which program it should use to run the dll-files I talked about before.

So here is my question: How can I make an installer that generates my project inside a .exe file so that it can run on every computer without needing a special program to run dll files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a standalone executable (.exe) file for your WPF project instead of having separate DLL files that need to be run using another program. To achieve this, you'll need to build your WPF application as a standalone executable, which includes all the necessary dependencies within the .exe file itself.

Here's a general approach you can follow:

**Build Configuration**: Ensure that you are building your project in **Release mode**. This optimizes the build and includes only necessary files.

Publishing Options: If you are using Visual Studio, you should look into the "Publish" feature. This allows you to create a publish profile that packages your application along with its dependencies into a standalone executable.

**Executable Output**: By default, WPF projects generate an executable (.exe) file in the "bin" folder of your project. However, this .exe file might still require some external DLLs to run. To embed these DLLs into the executable, you can follow these steps:

a. In Solution Explorer, right-click on your WPF project and select "Publish".

b. Choose a publish target, such as a folder on your computer.

c. Click on "Options" in the publish dialog.

d. Under "Deployment Mode," select "Self-contained" to include all the required libraries with the application.

e. Configure other settings as needed and then click "Save" to create a publish profile.

f. Click "Publish" to build the application.

Testing the Published Application: After publishing, navigate to the published folder and find the .exe file. You can now try running this .exe file on different computers to check if it works without needing external DLLs.

Installer: If you want to create an installer for your standalone executable, you can still use the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects extension that you mentioned. When setting up your installer project, make sure to include the standalone executable (.exe) file and any other necessary files.

Remember that creating a truly standalone executable might not always be possible, especially if your application relies on certain system-wide libraries or components that are not redistributable. In such cases, you might need to provide instructions for users to install those dependencies separately.